# Python/GAE Attribute Error - webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I am using [Nick Johnsons Webapp & Templates](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/11/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-2-Webapp-and-templates) application as a base for what I am trying to do. I am getting a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'" when I try to call the render_template. I know it is because when I instantiate the object "Capture" as X, it doesn't have a response property. I have looked everywhere to find a solution but I cannot find one anywhere.

NOTE: There are other ways to do this, but I need it to work as closely to how I have it setup!

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/userx/Documents/_FRESHCUTZ MEDIA/Google/GAE - Test web form 1 /testwebform1/main.py", line 41, in post
    x.calculateYear(name, age)
  File "/Users/userx/Documents/_FRESHCUTZ MEDIA/Google/GAE - Test web form 1 /testwebform1/main.py", line 49, in calculateYear
    self.response.write(self.render_template('index.html', **template_args))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

MAIN.PY

```
import os
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import jinja2

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @webapp2.cached_property
  def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

  def render_template(self, filename, **template_args):
        self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename, **template_args))

class MainPage(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    template_args = {}
    self.render_template('index.html', **template_args)

class CaptureDetails(BaseHandler):
  def post(self):
    name = self.request.get("name").strip()
    age = self.request.get("age").strip()

    x = Calculate()
    x.calculateYear(name, age)

class Calculate(BaseHandler):
    def calculateYear(self, name, age):
       template_args = {"age": age} 
       self.render_template('name.html', **template_args) 

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
      ('/', MainPage),
      ('/capture', CaptureDetails),
      ('/age', Calculate)
    ], debug=True)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Does it fit your criteria if you make `calculateYear` a function of your `BaseHandler` class (or elsewhere if more applicable)? As you guessed, your `x` isn't being treated as a proper `response`. When you invoke a `webapp2.RequestHandler` handler, it calls the method associated with the type of request (so in your case, since you are posting a form, it will call `post()`, as you know). When you instantiate `x` and call `calculateYear`, you aren't specifying a particular method (`def get(self)`, `def post(self)`, etc.), so there is no preparation of a `response` (when I have a chance I'll dig a little to confirm that this is actually the case - I could be mistaken :) ).

Can't test this right now, but assuming you need to call `calculateYear` from more than just the `CaptureDetails` handler, would this work? Here you would be referencing `self` in the context of your `post` method, which would invoke the `response` handling:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @webapp2.cached_property
  def jinja2(self):
      return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

  def render_template(self, filename, **template_args):
      self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename, **template_args))

  def calculateYear(self, name, age):
      template_args = {"age": age} 
      self.render_template('name.html', **template_args)
```

Which you could then call from your `CaptureDetails` handler like:

```
class CaptureDetails(BaseHandler):
  def post(self):
    name = self.request.get("name").strip()
    age = self.request.get("age").strip()

    # Call the function and write the response
    self.calculateYear(name, age)
```

Answer (score 1):

By instantiating `Calculate` yourself in your `CaptureDetails.post` method you're not creating it in the same way that `WSGIApplication` does, so the properties aren't available. Specifically, you're not passing a `response` to it, so not surprisingly trying to reference it doesn't work.

In this case, I'd copy the contents of `calculateYear` into your post method - you're not really saving anything by having to create the instance and then call the method on it.
If `calculateYear` gets more complicated, and you don't want the duplication, then I'd introduce a new method that could be called by both of your hander methods. (It's not really clear from this example though why the `Calculate` class exists - it doesn't have a 'get' method, so mapping it to `/age` as you have done isn't going to work.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `self.response.out.write` instead of `self.response.write`.

Comment: with webapp2 'out' is just a method that returns 'self' for compatibility with webapp